# EC2 Classic to VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Been on EC2 Classic for years and we're getting squeezed off.  I'm having trouble planning the migration for the following reasons:

- ec2 classic security groups don't see vpc security groups
- routing only seems possible through public internet

I need to migrate master/slave db and a redis cluster into the vpc, but I can't see a clear path for the two bullet points above.  Short of taking the site offline and importing all the data via dumps, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot migrate anything "LIVE" from classic to VPC. You need to take Snapshot, create AMI.. etc and then re-launch the whole thing from the scratch inside the VPC. There is no other way out.

For the security group (SG), VPC SG and EC2-classic SG do not mingle. You will have to create separate SGs inside the VPC.

You need to figure out what all things you want to host in public subnet of VPC (OR Private subnet of VPC). Things only inside the Public Subnet could be accessed from Internet.

e.g. you can have your Webserver in the Public Subnet while you can have the back-end Application server in the private subnet. This was just an example.

To make the long story short, you are eventually going to launch everything new in the VPC (take help of EC2 AMI, snapshot…etc so that the things that you will launch in the VPC will have your data)